# Jquery click animation keep going if clicked again before it's over

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

So i've made an animation for a shopping cart so that when someone clicks "buy", the shopping cart opens, a clone of the product appears, the clone disappears and the cart closes again. my problem is that when someone clicks the button multiple times, the animation starts over every time. what i would like is that the animation would keep going normally and when the cart's open, the clone of each product clicked appears and disappears, one after the other, and then the cart closes again, or at least something that doesn't look so glitchy.

my jquery:

```
$("input[name=\"comprar\"]").click(function(event) {
    //get form values
    var comprar = $(this).val();
    var form = $(this).parents("form");
    var cartData = form.serialize() + "&comprar="+ comprar;
    //submit form ajax
    if ($("div.minicart").length > 0){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: siteurl,
            data: cartData,
            success: function(cart){
                var target = $(event.target).parents("div.rproducts");
                $("div.minicart_container").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
                target.clone().insertBefore("div.minicart_container a");
                $("div.minicart_container div.rproducts input[type=submit]").css({"display":"none"});
                $("div.minicart_container div.rproducts").css({"margin":"10px 30px", "padding":"10px", "background-color":"#ffffff", "border-radius":"10px", "display":"none", "opacity":"0"});
                $("div.minicart_container div.rproducts").slideDown(1000);
                $("div.minicart_container div.rproducts").animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500);
                $("div.minicart_container div.rproducts").delay(800).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500);
                $("div.minicart_container div.rproducts").delay(100).slideUp(1000);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $("div.minicart_container div.rproducts").remove();
                }, 4000);
                //refresh cart price
                var getcart = $(cart).find("div.minicart").html();
                $("div.minicart").hide().html(getcart).fadeIn("fast");
                //remove clone immediately if button is clicked again
                $("input[name=\"comprar\"]").click(function(event) {
                    $("div.minicart_container div.rproducts").remove();
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to set a flag (bool) on start of animation,
and off it when animation finish.

After click before you start animation, you check if the flag is up.

Code is like this:

```
$("input[name=\"comprar\"]").click(function(event) {
 if(!inAnimation){
    inAnimation = true;
...
...
 setTimeout(function() {
                    $("div.minicart_container div.rproducts").remove();
                   inAnimation = false;
                }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: just the jquery, sorry